# Jenkins PromotedBuild and Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, promoted-builds

I have the following jenkins work flow :

I'm using a Build Flow to orchestrate several jobs.

```
Job 1 -> publish artifacts to artifactory
Job 2 -> publish artifacts to artifactory
Job 3 -> uses artifacts from artifactory
```

(I actually have several more jobs, with parallelization, that's why the Build Flow is particularly useful)

Now Job 3 might have used the artifact from Job1Build1 and from Job2Build2

I'd like to install a promotion on Job 1 and Job 2.

For instance, after Job3 has run, it should detect that it retrieved artifacts from Artifactory from J1B1 and J2B2, and therefore apply a promotion on these builds.

Is it possible to record such link without explicitly recording fingerprints in Jenkins (only relying on the fingerprints of the artifacts published to / retrieved from Artifactory) ?

Comment: I have a similar, but simpler issue - I have just Job 1 and Job 3. Right now, Job 1 triggers Job 3, but sometimes the artifacts seem to have not finished uploading to artifactory yet, and Job 3 fails. Is there a way to not trigger Job 3 until after the artifact has uploaded?

Comment: Your upload to artifactory should be a build step. I'm curry doing it inside my gradle build

Comment: My upload to artifactory is a build step - that doesn't seem to prevent the next step (triggering the next job) from happening before the upload completes.